# view.popup.watch is not a function -upgrading from arcgis 4.26 to 4.27

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I have a line of code that was working fine in ArcGIS javascript api 4.26.  Updating ArcGIS javascript api from 4.26 to 4.27, I am receiving this error:

```
view.popup.watch is not a function
```

Here is the failing line:

```
view.popup.watch("selectedFeature", (graphic) => {
```

Looks like esri deprecated this.  Does anyone know the correct replacement for performing this watch now on 4.27?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reactiveUtils` ([ArcGIS API - reactiveUtils](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-core-reactiveUtils.html#when)), it seems that the library is favoring this.

```
reactiveUtils.watch(
  () => view.popup.selectedFeature,
  (graphic) => {
    if (graphic) {
        // ...
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you cabesuon!  I switched to reactiveUtils as you mentioned and it works perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the "watch" that is the the problem, but that the Popup isn't available yet.  See the 4.27 popup changes in https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/4.27/#breaking-changes

- ... *if attempting to access the view.popup property before it is instantiated, some issues may occur. See [Loading the Popup](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#loading-the-popup) for details on how to update your apps to take advantage of these performance improvements.*

To use reactiveUtils to watch properties on the popup and its view model instead of the watch() method.

```
// This will throw an error that watch() is not a method // since the
popup hasn't been created yet. view.popup.watch("selectedFeature", ...)

// Call reactiveUtils.watch() on popup properties with optional
chaining. reactiveUtils.watch(() => view.popup?.selectedFeature, ...);
```

-- from [API Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#loading-the-popup)

Comment: Hi Bjorn thank you for your suggestion.  It was working correctly in 4.26.  Actually if I revert to 4.26, the watch works correctly.  It looks like esri is heading in a different direction by removing the option to use view.popup.watch in 4.27.